# Objective C - record audio noise

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I'm making an app that allows user to record audio.
I got it to work but when I playback the audio, the audio has a lot of static background noise. (like "sssssttttt").
Is there any property I can use to reduce that "sssssttttt" static background noise?

Below is the setting that I'm currently using

```
NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
    [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
    [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
    [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
    nil];
```

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: Do you get the same background noise when you use a different program to record ? If so then it's a hardware problem. You might also want to mention the platform here - is this Mac OS X or iOS ???

Comment: Hey Paul, the app that I use as a quality reference to doesn't have that background noise. Just this app that I'm making. This is for iOS. Thanks.

Comment: OK - I've re-tagged accordingly so that you're more likely to get an appropriate answer.

Comment: were u doing it for mac app?I need to record audio for mac app.can u please help me out